# How to unset object inside ResultSet?

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, orm, resultset

I'm trying to unset an Object inside my Result set. Not is a property inside, are the Users objects that not match with the filter selected by user on search page.

My table have hasMany association but for this case I need only check the first object.

Here is my code:

```
$usr = $this->User->find('all')
        ->select(['id','social','name','date_ctd'])
        ->where([$field . ' LIKE ' => '%' . $usr_txt_insert . '%'])
        ->contain('StatusUsr', function($q) {
            return $q->select(['id','id_usr','date_venc','situation']);
        })
        ->distinct();

//mathing the status here
if ($filter != "" && $filter != 'undefined') {
        $usr->matching('StatusUser')
        ->where(['situation' => $filter]);
}       

// try unset here
foreach($usr as $c) {
    if (isset($c->status_usr[0]->situation)) {
        if ($c->status_usr[0]->situation != $filter) {
           unset($c);
        }
    }
}
debug($cliente->all());exit;
```

In the code above, the last `foreach`, I'm compare with the first `situation` and compare with my filter passed. I tried to use the collections methods like `match`, `reject`, and `filter`, but nobody success was reached using these methods.

**Result:**

```
object(Cake\ORM\ResultSet) {
    'items' => [
        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\User) {
            'id' => (int) 106,
            'social' => 'Meow',
            'name' => 'Xuxa',
            'status_User' => [
                (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\StatusUsr) {
                    'id' => (int) 125,
                    'id_usr' => (int) 106,
                    'date_venc' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {
                        'time' => '2017-09-04T00:00:00+00:00',
                        'timezone' => 'UTC',
                        'fixedNowTime' => false
                    },
                    'situation' => 'ACTIVE'
                    ]
                },
                (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\StatusUsr) {
                    'id' => (int) 124,
                    'id_usr' => (int) 106,
                    'date_venc' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {
                        'time' => '2017-09-04T00:00:00+00:00',
                        'timezone' => 'UTC',
                        'fixedNowTime' => false
                    },
                    'situation' => 'ACTIVE'
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\User) {
            'id' => (int) 138,
            'social' => 'Core Lesain',
            'name' => 'Nome Fantasia',
            'status_User' => [
                (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\StatusUsr) {
                    'id' => (int) 132,
                    'id_usr' => (int) 138,
                    'date_venc' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {
                        'time' => '2017-09-08T00:00:00+00:00',
                        'timezone' => 'UTC',
                        'fixedNowTime' => false
                    },
                    'situation' => 'BLOCKED'
                    ]
                }
                (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\StatusUsr) {
                    'id' => (int) 122,
                    'id_usr' => (int) 138,
                    'date_venc' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {
                        'time' => '2017-08-08T00:00:00+00:00',
                        'timezone' => 'UTC',
                        'fixedNowTime' => false
                    },
                    'situation' => 'ACTIVE'
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        (int) 2 => object(App\Model\Entity\User) {
            'id' => (int) 139,
            'social' => ' Xuxa Social',
            'name' => 'Xuxa Fantasia',
            'status_User' => [
                (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\StatusUsr) {
                    'id' => (int) 134,
                    'id_usr' => (int) 139,
                    'date_venc' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {
                        'time' => '2017-09-09T00:00:00+00:00',
                        'timezone' => 'UTC',
                        'fixedNowTime' => false
                    },
                    'situation' => 'BLOCKED',
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not working on a query object and not a result set at the point you call the foreach. `$usr` seems to be a query object, and I don't see where `$cliente` is declared at all... I *assume* you want to do this:

```
$users = $cliente->all();
```

Or that

```
$users = $usr->all();
```

Either your code paste is incomplete or totally wrong.

Also you unset the local variable `$c`, but not the value of the array in your code.

Try this.

```
foreach($users as $key => $user) {
    if (isset($user->status_usr[0]->situation)) {
        if ($user->status_usr[0]->situation !== $filter) {
           unset($users[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

And please use proper words, these mutilated abbreviations are terrible and nobody ever will know what "c" is but having a hard time to read and understand this code. Removing the `e` from `user` is pointless as well. Also use strict comparison (!== vs !=) whenever possible.

You should follow [a proper coding standard](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html) like the one Cake uses or directly [PSR](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/) (minus their silly spaces). Here is a non boring talk about writing nice to read code https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZsHMHukIlJY

Comment: Your code is really bad to read and I'm not sure if you pasted everything you have. Please see my updated answer. However, you want to modify a result set but you're working on a query object - I think. Also filtering result sets can be done via map/reduce -> https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#map-reduce

Comment: Hi, I solved my problem removing the filter from my search, it's more easy tha way. But i'm have other search function that i'm trying implement this filter. Thanks a lot for you help with this question! [Another search function.](https://github.com/Thormenta77/hello/blob/a273a6cb2fb10a8d59869b84603779bae593e014/file.php)

Comment: I tried the plugin today, and it give me the same result. Thanks for the help.